# String replaceAll hyphen not working java 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
String test = "Vol. 5 −";
        test = test.replaceAll("\u2014", "");
        test = test.replaceAll("//-", "");
        test = test.replaceAll("-","");
        System.out.println(test);
```

Still got "Vol. 5 -" in output tried in all possibilities

Comment: The `−` is a [Unicode Character 'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm). It is not a ['HYPHEN-MINUS' (U+002D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm) or an ['EM DASH' (U+2014)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm). --- To see what character it actually is, copy/paste to http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php

Comment: That's not a hyphen

Comment: there is no hyphen in Vol. 5 −

Comment: how can we type hyphen then. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Same way you did the other two: `"//-"` and `"-"`. Those are both `\u002D` (hyphen) characters. If by "type hyphen" you meant the character in the first string, use `\u2212`.

Comment: just `"\u2212"` based on Andreas first comment

Comment: Saved my day thanks

Comment: also check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4 for important information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String test = "Vol. 5 −";
    test = test.replaceAll("\u2212", "");
    System.out.println(test);
```

Works fine

Comment: Your `test` string is not the same string as in the question. The question was how to change the string in the question, not some other string.

Comment: will not work for author since its another character, not ASCII 45 - copy&paste it from the question to check (Java uses Unicode, not (only) ASCII)

Comment: @Andreas ahh ok, sorry I have'nt noticed

Comment: As @ThomasBanderas pointed out the correct unicode for the minus you are using is "\u2212" and not "\u2014"